# Help do with calculating if the function is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

Okay, so I'm trying to use a theorem that says if the derivative to the function has a max at the given interval then the function is uniformly continuous there.

I don't know how to continue my calculations to find the max value to the derivative.Here is the task and what I have done:

Find out if $$f(x)=x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ is uniformly continuous at $$I=(0,1)$$

My calculations:

$$f'(x)=2x \cos⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+ \sin⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq 2x \cos⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+ \sin⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

But here it stops for me, because the $0$ in the interval makes it hard for me to understand what to do with the expression. Does anyone have some tips? How do I find the max-value to the derivative?

Comment: You have just shown that |f'(x)| < 3....

Comment: But how you find it? How do you prove that $$x*cos(1/x)<1$$ ?

Comment: $ x \in (0,1) $ so both $ |x| $ and $ |cos| $ are less or equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the proof of the OP:

We have
$$
f'(x)=2x \cos⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+ \sin⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) 
$$
and hence
$$
|f'(x)|\leq 2x \Big|\cos⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Big|
+ \Big|\sin⁡\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Big|\le 3.
$$
MVP provides that for every $x,y\in(0,1)$, there is a $\xi \in(x,y)\subset(0,1)$, 
such that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)||x-y|\le 3|x-y|
$$
and hence $f$ is uniformly continuous ($\delta=\varepsilon/3$).

Comment: I understand that the max value to $$sin(1/x)$$ is 1. But the thing that makes me confused is that $$x*sin(1/x)<1$$. I understand why, because you use the fact that $$\frac{sin(u)}{u}=1$$. So I hoped there was a similar logic I could apply to $$xcos(1/x)$$. So I'm just supposed to look at the max value to $$cos(1/x)$$ alone, and ignore the x infront? Do we do this because we know that this expression will be less than 1 or equal to one in just this interval? I hope you understand what I mean.